# QMidArea & SubWindow : detect when subWindow hit borders

Tags: c++, qt

I'm here because of a problem which remain from a long time >< !
I use Qt to develop an interactive screen using a QMidArea for multiple windows.

I have this configuration :

- A class A which inherits from QWidget
- A class B which inherits from A and adds some features
- Then I add B into a new SubWindow.

But the problem i have is now to detect (maybe with signals and slots) when i drag a subWindow out of the QMainwindow containing all the application.
I tried to implement drag and drop into A but it clearly doesn't work because it's not A which is dragged but the subwindow...
My real aim is to detect when my subwindow hit the left border of the mainwindow.

Anyone has an idea ? 
Thanks !

Comment: Dragging a subwindow is not a drag-n-drop operation but a move operation, so you should install an event filter on the subwindow and process its `QEvent::Move` event. You can use `QWidget::parentWidget` to access outer widget from A and B.

Comment: I Don't really understand the aim of parentWidget() ?
I overrided the moveEvent in the class A (to have this event catch for each class B), but it only takes effect when i use buttons at top of subWindow to resize it to full screen...It's not detected when i move the subWindow in the mainWindow...

Comment: You need to catch move event of the subwindow, not the inner widget. So you need to either subclass subwindow and override its moveEvent or install an event filter on the subwindow object.

Comment: Okay thanks :) !
But if i override move event on a subwindow subclass, when i add it to my central area, it will create a new subwindow containing my subwindow right ? It will report the problem..?